# Change speed and position stepper motor in ARDUINO

Tags: arduino

I am trying to move a certain distance from the motor step by step with a specific speed when i press a button. I am moving the distance without problem, but I cannot change the speed.
I tried with the following instructions

```
MOTOR.setseped (speed)
MOTOR.move(DRIVER_PASOS);
```

and

```
 speed()
 MOTOR.move(DRIVER_PASOS);
```

The motor always move the distance correctly but with a default speed

some suggestions of how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally an expert on this subject.( Stepper motor ) But As far as I know motor speed can control with two basic way one of them voltage the other is current.
You should look your motors current consumption values from datasheet. Also you should check voltage current consumption. And you should ensure that  give motor exactly what it needs.
if you use driver circuit , you should check the switching time and drivers components works properly.
Generally people try to use MCU pins to control motor. But every time it is not right way. You should use driver shield (like these Adafruit Motor/Stepper/Servo Shield for Arduino kit - v1.2) . MCU pins can provide limitted current.